# Write Smarty template output to a static HTMl file

Tags: php, smarty

I have layouts created for marketing emails made using Smarty templates, which I need to convert to static HTML files.

Is there a method that does something like:

```
$smarty->display('index.tpl') [write to file with pattern title-yyyymm-orig.htm]
```

and that writes the html file in the same directory as my smarty index file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a workaround

```
 // get output 
 $output = $smarty->fetch('foo.tpl'); 

 // write to file 
 $file = 'title-'.date('Y-m',time()).'-orig.htm'; #FIXED
 file_put_contents($file,$output); 

 // send to browser 
 echo $output;
```

Comment: I get Parse Error in this bit:  `$file = 'title-'.date('Y-m',time()).'-orig.htm');` Does it need an opening bracket?

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake it is fixed

Comment: Fixed parse error with an opening bracket, but I don’t see a result. There’s no new file in the same directory as the php file

Comment: Ah, there it is. However: `failed to open stream: Permission denied in ` etc. Perms on that folder are 755

Comment: dump the result of file_put_contents and you see that a file was created .... better prefix the absolute path for storing

Comment: Where do I write the prefix?

Comment: Also, could I put a smarty variable in place of the date string - it actually needs to be a static number, but unique to each project